# What do you call films that show the same timeline and can be watched in parallel

Tags: film-techniques

I don't know the "technical word" or category or kind of films where there is only one timeline but the story is told in two or more films.

The films have exactly the same timing such that you can play one in one TV and another in another, and they show the same timeline.  One shows the life of one character and the other the life of another.  Sometimes the films show the same situation.

I remember two films (but sorry I don't remember the titles). They were European romantic films which showed simultaneously the same plot but one with his perspective and the other hers.

I remember that some European TV channels streamed these films at the same time in two channels and you could change the channel and see the same timeline. I recall that these films were not Spanish, maybe they were French or Belgian.

I was looking in the English wikipedia about interactive films or something like that, because I think there are few films of this "unnamed category" but I don't know the "word".

What is the term for this kind of movie making.

Comment: [Category:Multi-screen film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Multi-screen_film) is not the category (in wikipedia). But it is some similar. And somebody asked years ago in https://www.quora.com/Has-there-ever-been-2-movies-of-the-same-story-shot-from-2-different-points-of-view .

Comment: Please let me know if my edits change the meaning of what you intended to ask.  I tried to make the question a little more idiomatic English.  "History" in particular isn't quite the same as plot or timeline.

Comment: I suspect this sort of thing is rare enough that it probably doesn't have a *formal* term associated with it.  I might call them "crossover films" or "concurrent timeline" films to describe the effect, but that's just the words *I'd* use.  Don't suppose you remember the names of those two romance films?  I'd like to check them out.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, Wiki refers to them as "companion pieces", although there is no link to that term on Wiki to better describe it.

I came to this conclusion by looking up the only American films I knew of that had this sort of plot line; [*Flags Of Our Fathers* (2006)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0418689/) and [*Letters From Iwo Jima* (2006)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0498380/).

This is different from [Twin Films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_films), which would be something like [*Tombstone* (1993)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108358/) and [*Wyatt Earp* (1994)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111756/).

Comment: According to IMDB, they have different lengths. Is that an error? For the kind of synchronized viewing that the OP is talking about, I would have expected them to have the same runtime.

Answer (score 0):

While you're description is very specific and so neither one of these may be quite right, usually if things run "along side" each other in time (and are not within the same work, meaning film, book, comic, tv series, etc), then they are sometimes refereed to as a concurrent story or a [sidequel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sidequel#:%7E:text=Noun,characters%20in%20a%20different%20setting).

> sidequel (plural sidequels)
>
> A type of sequel which portrays events that occur at the same time as
> the original work, but with different characters in a different
> setting

Again, as you mentioned, your two referenced characters may share a setting, but perhaps not all the time? This is the closest thing I could think of.

Comment: I'm have recently read, and continue to read, Star Wars mass media project that is set in a new High Republic era. There is 1 book that acts as a foundation, but from there the events of other books/comics unfold from different points within that first work and then begin to move beyond it.

Comment: So for instance Into the Dark is both a prequel, a sidequel, and a sequel to Light of the Jedi while parts of it also run concurrent to Marvel's High Republic, which is only on issue 3, but both those stories are relying on a death of one character from Light of the Jedi & both feature the same new villain attacking different characters. I have no idea what to call a project that unfolds/operates like this, LOL!